# Utilizing the existing isolated ethernet line

Tags: uart, ethernet

I am trying to figure out a simple circuitry that would allow to "hack" the existing ethernet jack in a device, to allow for uart communication as well. Since it is an isolated connector (ethernet transformer), it should stay so. Are there any known and tested methods/ IC's for allowing for raw serial communication over isolated ethernet pairs? The first thing that came up to my mind is to simply threat one pair as RS485 TX and the other one as RS485 RX (so full duplex is allowed), but the issue is that there are transformers in between.

Comment: POE is a thing you may be able to get inspiration from, but anything could kill your circuit since ethernet is isolated for a reason.

Comment: Depends on the existing Ethernet jack. Is it a bare jack with external magnetics which exposes all pins, or is it a magjack which does not even connect to the cable wiring directly?

Comment: Its an unisolatet ethernet jack connector with external magnetics- it is isolated. I want to connect behimd the iaolation already, where the pins go to the PHY.

Comment: You would have to encode/decode the uart data with Manchester or similar scheme to remove the DC level. Something like a psoc5 might be able to do this easily.

Comment: Yes, and I was wondering whether there are any non complicated IC's, like simple transceivers, that could do just that for me. PSOC5 is quite big, but I get the idea, thank you.